# How to read dropbox online using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently reading from dropbox offline using pyspark on my local machine using this code

```py
pre_test_quiz_df = spark \
     .read \
     .option('header', 'true') \
     .csv('/Users/jamie/Dropbox/Moodle/Course uptake/data use/UserDetails.csv')
```

While working on from a server I am not able to read dropbox on my local machine. Is there a way to read the same file but from the dropbox on my browser.

Have tried reading with pandas and converting to pyspark dataframe although it did not work.

Comment: There is some useful info missing to be able to answer the question, for example what was the code you tried that didn't work? What failed, and with which error message?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. I didn't find any direct way of doing this, so the next alternative was using the dropbox API, which works pretty well. You can check their documentation or youtube on how to set up the API.